# AccessDeniedException: 403 does not have storage.objects.list access to config-management-release

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have Google Cloud console account with anthos enabled. When configuring anthos config management, I am getting accessdeniedexception.

Command Ran :

```
 gsutil cp gs://config-management-release/released/latest/config-management-operator.yaml config-management-operator.yaml
```

> Exception : AccessDeniedException: 403 account-dv@fabric-275411.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to config-management-release.

Service account has required privileges. But still throwing the exception. How to solve this issue? Tried with by creating service account with different names.

Below are the roles associated with serviceaccount:

- roles/owner
- roles/editor
- roles/viewer
- roles/compute.admin
- roles/compute.securityAdmin
- roles/compute.loadBalancerAdmin
- roles/compute.networkAdmin
- roles/servicenetworking.networksAdmin
- roles/iam.securityAdmin
- roles/iam.serviceAccountKeyAdmin
- roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
- roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin
- roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
- roles/container.admin
- roles/container.clusterAdmin
- roles/container.clusterViewer
- roles/gkehub.connect
- roles/gkehub.admin
- roles/gkehub.viewer
- roles/stackdriver.accounts.editor
- roles/logging.admin
- roles/logging.configWriter
- roles/logging.viewer
- roles/monitoring.admin
- roles/storage.admin
- roles/storage.objectAdmin
- roles/storage.objectViewer
- roles/redis.admin
- roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin
- roles/composer.environmentAndStorageObjectAdmin

Comment: The access to Anthos config-management-release requires Anthos entitlement
as described in this [doc][1].   
Have you contacted Sales about it? Once you obtain the Anthos entitlement, the
permission error should be resolved.


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/anthos-config-management/downloads

Comment: May be usefull ;)    
http://cloud.google.com/contact